# How to disable the input text based on *ngif in angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

how to disable textbox if the ngifcondition satisfies on text box field.

```
Below didnt work for me


<input [ngClass]="{'disbaled' : !isprecheck}" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"
                           [(ngModel)]="stunt.title" #Title="ngModel" required minlength="1" maxlength="255">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use declarative forms as now use the `disabled` attribute like `[disabled]="condition"` but if you are learning angular I suggest to take a look at reactive forms they are way more powerful: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

component.html

```
<input [disabled]="isprecheck" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" [(ngModel)]="stunt.title" #Title="ngModel" required minlength="1" maxlength="255">
```

component.ts

```
isprecheck: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

What your current code does is to add a class named `disbaled` to your input element if **isprecheck** condition is satisfied.

Also using *ngIf hides your input if the Boolean condition negates.

If you want to show the element but disable it, use [disabled] with your boolean.

```
<input [ngClass]="{'disbaled' : !isprecheck}" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" [(ngModel)]="stunt.title" #Title="ngModel" required minlength="1" maxlength="255" [disabled]=“!isprecheck”>
```